# How to prove given relation on set is partial order?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A$ is a poset where every chain has an upper bound in $A$ and $a$ is any element in $A$.
let $$C_a=\{x∈A∣a≤x\}$$
Can some one help me how to show $(C_a,\le )$ is a poset and how it satisfies hypothesis of Zorn's Lemma?

To show $(C_a, \le)$ is a poset I know I should show it is reflixive, antisymmetric and transitive. But I dont know how to even start it. Can any help me?

Comment: Are you ordering the $C_a$ or are you restricting the domain to a particular $C_a$?

Comment: I am restricting domsin to a particular Ca.

Answer (score 1):

The poset properties are inherited directly from $A$.  What's more difficult is that every chain in $C_a$ has an upper bound in $C_a$.  It has an upper bound in $A$, since $A$ has that property, but that upper bound needs to be in $C_a$.